# Why can't my listbox show the bound values when I can confirm that my collection does have values?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

**Problem Summary:**

I'm having a bit of problem with my ListBox, it's unable to show the values of a collection it's bound to, which is weird because I've iterated through the collection and can confirm that they do have values. Also, I've bound another collection (which is contained within the same class as the first 1) to another ListBox and it works perfectly so the path I've set my bindings to does work as intended.

**What I've done:**

To try and figure out where this problem lies, I created a checklist of possible causes:

1. > Does the observable collection have a value in the first place? Maybe
   >   it's not showing anything because there's actually nothing in it?

**Result:** Passed - I created a command that MessageBox.Shows the content of the collection and it displayed the proper string value

2. > Does the binding actually work? Maybe my DataContext is incorrect?
   >   Maybe I'm in the wrong path/class?

**Result:** Passed - I have three ListBoxes:

1. `ListBox(A)` is bound to the ObservableCollection `FirstName`
2. `ListBox(B)` is bound to the ObservableCollection `LastName`
3. `ListBox(C)` is bound to the ObservableCollection `All` which only has a getter that combines the values of `FirstName` and `LasName`

They're all contained within the same class and both `ListBox(A)` and `ListBox(B)`'s bindings work so I'm certain that the path of my `ListBox(C)` is correct.

3. > Does the collection get notified of changes?

**Result:** Passed - AFAIK ObservableCollections can automatically notify add/remove actions so I shouldn't have to implement it if those are only my requirements. I did implement it though since I want it to raise it on edits as well.

Unfortunately I can't seem to pinpoint the exact problem, does the ListBox have any problems with an IEnumerable that only has a get?

**My Code:**

I recreated a simple illustration of my implementation:

> MainModel.cs

```
public class MainModel
{
    public class Customer : INotifyImplementation
    {
        public Customer()
        {
            FirstName = "";
            LastName = "";
        }

        private string firstName;
        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return firstName; }
            set { firstName = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("FirstName");
                RaisePropertyChanged("FullName");
            }
        }

        private string lastName;
        public string LastName
        {
            get { return lastName; }
            set { lastName = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("LastName");
                RaisePropertyChanged("FullName");
            }
        }

        public string FullName
        {
            get { return GetFullName(); }
        }

        public string GetFullName()
        {
            return FirstName + " " + LastName;
        }
    }

    public class CustomerFieldErrors : INotifyImplementation
    {
        public CustomerFieldErrors()
        {
            FirstName = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            LastName = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        }

        private ObservableCollection<string> firstName;
        public ObservableCollection<string> FirstName
        {
            get { return firstName; }
            set { firstName = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("FirstName");
                RaisePropertyChanged("All");
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<string> lastName;
        public ObservableCollection<string> LastName
        {
            get { return lastName; }
            set { lastName = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("LastName"); 
                RaisePropertyChanged("All");
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<string> All
        {
            get { return GetAllErrors(); }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<string> GetAllErrors()
        {
            ObservableCollection<string> allErrors = new ObservableCollection<string>();

            foreach(string i in FirstName)
            {
                allErrors.Add(i);
            }

            foreach (string i in LastName)
            {
                allErrors.Add(i);
            }

            return allErrors;
        }
    }

    public class CustomerFieldRestrictions : INotifyImplementation
    {
        public CustomerFieldRestrictions()
        {
            FirstName = new FieldRestrictions();
            LastName = new FieldRestrictions();
        }

        private FieldRestrictions firstName;
        public FieldRestrictions FirstName
        {
            get { return firstName; }
            set { firstName = value; }
        }

        private FieldRestrictions lastName;
        public FieldRestrictions LastName
        {
            get { return lastName; }
            set { lastName = value; }
        }
    }

    public class FieldRestrictions : INotifyImplementation
    {
        public FieldRestrictions()
        {
            MinCharacterLength = 0;
            MaxCharacterLength = 0;
        }

        private int minCharacterLength;
        public int MinCharacterLength
        {
            get { return minCharacterLength; }
            set { minCharacterLength = value; RaisePropertyChanged("MinCharacterLength"); }
        }

        private int maxCharacterLength;
        public int MaxCharacterLength
        {
            get { return maxCharacterLength; }
            set { maxCharacterLength = value; RaisePropertyChanged("MaxCharacterLength"); }
        }
    }
}

public class INotifyImplementation : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    readonly Action<object> _execute;
    readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, object productEditCanUse) : this(execute, null)
    {

    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

> MainViewModel.cs

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyImplementation
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        NewCustomer = new Customer();
        NewCustomerFieldErrors = new CustomerFieldErrors();
        NewCustomerFieldRestrictions = new CustomerFieldRestrictions()
        {
            FirstName = new FieldRestrictions()
            {
                MinCharacterLength = 1,
                MaxCharacterLength = 5
            },
            LastName = new FieldRestrictions()
            {
                MinCharacterLength = 0,
                MaxCharacterLength = 5
            }
        };
        CreateNewCustomerCommand = new RelayCommand(CreateNewCustomer, CreateNewCustomerCanUse);
        ShowNewCustomerAllFieldErrorsCommand = new RelayCommand(ShowNewCustomerAllFieldErrors, ShowNewCustomerAllFieldErrorsCanUse);
    }

    private Customer newCustomer;
    public Customer NewCustomer
    {
        get { return newCustomer; }
        set { newCustomer = value; RaisePropertyChanged("NewCustomer"); }
    }

    private CustomerFieldErrors newCustomerFieldErrors;
    public CustomerFieldErrors NewCustomerFieldErrors
    {
        get { return newCustomerFieldErrors; }
        set { newCustomerFieldErrors = value; RaisePropertyChanged("NewCustomerFieldErrors"); }
    }

    private CustomerFieldRestrictions newCustomerFieldRestrictions;
    public CustomerFieldRestrictions NewCustomerFieldRestrictions
    {
        get { return newCustomerFieldRestrictions; }
        set { newCustomerFieldRestrictions = value; RaisePropertyChanged("NewCustomerFieldRestrictions"); }
    }

    public RelayCommand CreateNewCustomerCommand { get; private set; }
    protected void CreateNewCustomer(object message)
    {

    }
    protected bool CreateNewCustomerCanUse(object message)
    {
        NewCustomerFieldErrors = new CustomerFieldErrors();

        if (NewCustomer.FirstName.Length < NewCustomerFieldRestrictions.FirstName.MinCharacterLength)
            NewCustomerFieldErrors.FirstName.Add("First Name minimum length is: " + NewCustomerFieldRestrictions.FirstName.MinCharacterLength);
        if (NewCustomer.FirstName.Length > NewCustomerFieldRestrictions.FirstName.MaxCharacterLength)
            NewCustomerFieldErrors.FirstName.Add("First Name maximum length is: " + NewCustomerFieldRestrictions.FirstName.MaxCharacterLength);

        if (NewCustomer.LastName.Length < NewCustomerFieldRestrictions.LastName.MinCharacterLength)
            NewCustomerFieldErrors.LastName.Add("Last Name minimum length is: " + NewCustomerFieldRestrictions.LastName.MinCharacterLength);
        if (NewCustomer.LastName.Length > NewCustomerFieldRestrictions.LastName.MaxCharacterLength)
            NewCustomerFieldErrors.LastName.Add("Last Name maximum length is: " + NewCustomerFieldRestrictions.LastName.MaxCharacterLength);

        if (NewCustomerFieldErrors.FirstName.Count == 0 && NewCustomerFieldErrors.LastName.Count == 0)
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    public RelayCommand ShowNewCustomerAllFieldErrorsCommand { get; private set; }

    protected void ShowNewCustomerAllFieldErrors(object message)
    {
        string allErrors = "";

        foreach(string i in NewCustomerFieldErrors.All)
        {
            allErrors += i + Environment.NewLine;
        }

        MessageBox.Show(allErrors);
    }

    protected bool ShowNewCustomerAllFieldErrorsCanUse(object message)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

> MainView.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainView : UserControl
{
    public MainView()
    {
        DataContext = new MainViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

> XAML

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="512" Margin="60,38,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="214">
        <Label Content="First Name Error:" Margin="0,20,0,0"/>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding NewCustomerFieldErrors.FirstName}" Height="100"/>
        <Label Content="Last Name Error:" Margin="0,20,0,0"/>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding NewCustomerFieldErrors.LastName}" Height="100"/>
        <Label Content="All Errors:" Margin="0,20,0,0"/>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding NewCustomerFieldErrors.All}" Height="100"/>
        <Button Content="Show All Errors" Margin="0,20,0,0" Command="{Binding ShowNewCustomerAllFieldErrorsCommand}" Height="40"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="416" Margin="398,74,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="214">
        <Label Content="First Name" Margin="0,20,0,0"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding NewCustomer.FirstName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="100"/>
        <Label Content="Last Name" Margin="0,20,0,0"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding NewCustomer.LastName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="100"/>
        <Button Content="Create Customer" Margin="0,20,0,0" Command="{Binding CreateNewCustomerCommand}" Height="40"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**What I expected to happen:**

I expected the ListBox(C, the one bound to the All property) to list all the errors like what the MessageBox is showing.

**Here's a clip of what I'm experiencing**

https://gfycat.com/obesecheapkoi

**I've did some new tests on Snoop**

1. ListBox A (bound to NewCustomerFieldErrors.FirstName)

[image]

2. ListBox B (bound to NewCustomerFieldErrors.MiddleName)

[image]

3. ListBox C (bound to NewCustomerFieldErrors.All)

[image]

4. Apparently the ListBox C is pointing towards a blank collection, so I went to my DataContext to double check but found it to be populated, which contradicts what the ListBox C's ItemsSource is saying.

[image]

Comment: Not sure what all this is supposed to do. However, `ItemsSource="{Binding NewCustomerFieldErrors.FirstName}"` looks odd. A name is certainly not a collection of items. You may want to read this first: [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview).

Comment: The `NewCustomerFieldErrors` uses the `CustomerFieldErrors` class which is a collection of strings, it's used to store multiple errors with the current string like min length, max length, regex mismatch, etc. I'll upload  a gif of its implementation.

Comment: Maybe, but what collection is supposed to be provided by the property path `NewCustomerFieldErrors.FirstName`? Makes no sense to me. Seriously, read the article about data templating. It explains how to use ListBoxes.

Comment: The ListBox interprets the collection just fine for my use-case, it's a simple collection of strings. The ListBox A and B shows all the error strings correctly, the ListBox C has exactly the same type as them so it should work as well. I've used snoop and apparently, the ListBox C is pointing towards a collection that's blank BUT after going into my DataContext, delved to All and find it to be populated with the FirstName and LastName errors.

Comment: IF the ListBox A and B didn't show the strings then sure I can agree that the problem is with templating and how it can't understand the bound values BUT it's not, they can both be seen on the ListBoxes just fine and if you snoop through their sources, you can see it properly populated. Now the ListBox C HAS THE SAME TYPE and should be equally interpreted as well BUT after using snoop I've found a deeper problem, apparently the collection it's bound to HAS NO VALUE for reasons I still don't understand at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A BIG BIG thanks to Peter Fleischer from MSDN!

**The Solution**

> RaisePropertyChanged(string.Empty);

Simply adding that code after I was done adding/removing contents from both the `FirstName error` and `LastName error` collections did the trick.

**The Explanation**

Basically my problem all along was: 
***The All property wasn't notified of the change***

While I personally haven't confirmed this with him, my interpretation of the problem was that I was not raising the All property change, I thought that by Raising it when `FirstName error` and `LastName error` changes (through add/remove) was enough but it was not, simply adding/removing instances from the collection wasn't enough for it to warrant the Raise Property Change I placed on the `FirstName error` and `LastName error` model. So his solution was for me to manually raise it when I add/remove stuff from the collection.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue has to do with binding to the All property. When the binding to All is done, the Method GetAllErrors returns to it a new instance of ObservableCollection. When new errors are added, they are not added to the original instance; thus, it never needs to get refreshed.

```
    public ObservableCollection<string> All
    {
        get { return GetAllErrors(); }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<string> GetAllErrors()
    {
        ObservableCollection<string> allErrors = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        foreach(string i in FirstName)
        {
            allErrors.Add(i);
        }

        foreach (string i in LastName)
        {
            allErrors.Add(i);
        }

        return allErrors;
    }
```